# How can I programmatically get certificates from Firefox?

Tags: c++, security, firefox, ssl

I would like my web client application (which uses OpenSSL) to be able to use the certificates stored by Firefox, meaning I would like to tell OpenSSL "trust these certificates" and give it the list of those trusted by Firefox. I've already done this for the certificates in the Windows certificate store but I know Firefox has its own list.

The certificates are stored in cert8.db and key3.db in my Firefox profile directory, but how can my code get access to the individual certificates stored there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox uses the NSS library to manage certificates. You can find more information about NSS at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NSS

You will have to use the NSS APIs to access the db files that you have found in your profile directory. You can extract certificates in a common format like PEM and then import those in your application using OpenSSL.

Comment: Can you perform operations on the database while firefox is running?